# Elegant way to check if a list contains int, str, tuple and sub-list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote some script, but I have to add some condition; the user puts a list and it must contain at least one of these types (tuple, int,s tr and sub-list).

Is there an elegant way to do that without 4 if?

I thought about for loop and using `isinstance(i, type)` but its tricky, because it runs over and over and ask the different 'questions' about one kind of type

```
for i in List:
  if isinstance(i,int):
    if isinstance(i,str)
```

As you see this is not very elegant. I thought about putting new variable `i,j,k` for each kind of type and maybe do 4 for loops:

```
for
  for
   for
    for
```

Any ideas and clues are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tuple of different types with `isinstance`:

```
>>> isinstance('a', (str, list, tuple, int))
True
```

Combine with `any`

```
>>> data = [1, 'a', (2, 4, 6)]
>>> any(isinstance(x, (str, list, tuple, int)) for x in data)
True
```

or, if you want to do something with the objects of one these types:

```
for x in data:
    if isinstance(x, (str, list, tuple, int)):
        print('found')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a helper function "has":

```
def has(items, t):
    for item in items:
        if isinstance(item, t):
            return True
    return False

def check(items):
    return has(items, int)   and has(items, str) \
       and has(items, tuple) and has(items, list)
```

If you want to be more compact (but less readable), use "any" and "all":

```
def has(item, t):
     return any([isinstance(items, t) for item in items])

def check(items):
     return all([has(items, t) for t in (str, int, tuple, list)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function. Quoting docs:

> **any(iterable)**
>
> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return `False`.

Sample usage:

```
expected_types = {int, str, tuple, list}  # set of expected types
for i in seq:
    if any(isinstance(i, t) for t in expected_types):
        pass  # do something
```

To check all elements of sequence you may use built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function. So, to check all elements of sequence you may simply use:

```
expected_types = {int, str, tuple, list}
if all(any(isinstance(i, t) for t in expected_types) for i in seq):
    pass  # condition is sufficient
```

Both `all()` and `any()` performs short-circuiting, so operation has reasonable performance. If you don't care about subclasses you may check type - it speeds up `isinstance(i, t) for t in expected_types` from `O(n)` to `O(1)`.

```
expected_types = {int, str, tuple, list}
if all(type(i) in expected_types for i in seq):
    pass  # condition is sufficient, but not for subclasses of int, str, tuple or list
```

All checks above tests if all objects are instances of one of `expected_types`, but not if all types occurs in sequence. If you want to ensure "at least one of each type" condition you may use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
c = collections.Counter(type(o) for o in seq)
if all(c[t] >= 1 for t in {int, list, tuple, str}):
    pass  # seq contains at least one of each type
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the type of an object, you can use the built-in [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function. Passing an object as the only parameter will return the type object of that object:

```
 eg:
    a=5
    type(a) will return 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for all instances if pass then use `all` otherwise use `any` as below.

e.g.

```
types = set(['int','str','dict'])#Used set to ensure no duplicate
l = ['s',3,{'s':3}]
for j in types:
    if any(isinstance(i,eval(j)) for i in l):
        print 'passed'
```

Output-

```
passed
passed
passed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in `all` and `any`:

```
all([any(lambda x: isInstance(x,i), lst_to_check) for i in instances_list])
```