# how can I exit program If there is no number in list(python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list

```
import sys
x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

something happened here and list of x changed like this.

```
x = [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A']]
```

if all list fill in 'A' or 'B', result should be like this

```
print('there is no number in the list')
exit()
```

So how can I exit program If there is no number in this list(python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to check if a list contains int, str, tuple and sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129359/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-list-contains-int-str-tuple-and-sub-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
try:
    if all(value.isalpha() for lists in x for value in lists):
        print('there is no number in the list')
        exit()
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

This block:

```py
try:
    <code>
except AttributeError:
   pass
```

will allow avoiding if the value in the list is not a string.

#### isalpha doc: [str.isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

> Return True if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise. Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this is different from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode Standard.